# Is it possible to share my character's profile through a web page?

Tags: path-of-exile

[Battle.net](http://battle.net) and [Steam](http://steamcommunity.com) provide such interfaces.  Is it possible with Path of Exile ?
It's already possible to see all your character's information directly from [their website](http://pathofexile.com), but is it possible to share it with someone else ?

Comment: You can link to the passive skill tree (which is static since all the info about skill nodes is encoded in the url) and you can link single items in the forum - although i don't recall how that works, but that's about it afaik.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's now possible at the following url: `http://www.pathofexile.com/account/view-profile/<account name>/`

See [this example](http://www.pathofexile.com/account/view-profile/Bleric/).